# Recursive call to class method doesn't return value on first call - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have a class with setter/getter methods, but the getter method doesn't return a value on my initial call:

```py
import random

class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}

    def set_value(self, k):
        self.data[k] = random.random()

    def get_value(self, k):
        if self.data.get(k) is not None:
            return self.data.get(k)

        self.set_value(k)
        self.get_value(k)
```

Now if I initiate this class and call for a value like 4, on first call it assign a value for 4, but doesn't return it eventhou I'm calling it after the setter function:

```py
d = Data()

d.get_value(4) # returns None

d.data # {4: 0.7578261616519488}

d.get_value(4) # returns 0.7578261616519488
```

Comment: maybe return get_value(self,k) in get_value method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't *return* the value returned by the recursive call.

```
def get_value(self, k):
    if self.data.get(k) is not None:
        return self.data.get(k)

    self.set_value(k)
    return self.get_value(k)
```